# Function to identify upper/lower case letters C

Tags: c, string, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to create a function that will identify whether the first letter input is upper or lower case then output the rest of the string in that same case(upper/lower).

For example, `"Hi there"` would become `"HI THERE"`.

I'm not familiar with `fgets`. Once I run it I can input and press enter and the program doesn't run. I'm not getting any compiler errors. I believe I went wrong in the void shift function.

Also, I know `gets` is not recommended, is `fgets` similar? Or is it better to use `scanf`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void shift (char *my_string); // Function declaration

int main()
{
  char inputstring[50];

  printf("Enter a string\n");
  char *my_string = inputstring;
  shift(my_string); // Function
}

void shift (char *my_string) // Function definition
{
  int i =0;
  char ch;

  for(i=0; i<50; i++)
    fgets(my_string, 50, stdin);

  while(my_string[i])
  {
    if(ch>='A' && ch<= 'Z') // When first char is uppercase
    {
      putchar (toupper(my_string[i]));
      i++;
    }
    else if (ch>='a' && ch <= 'z') // When first char is lowercase
    {
      putchar(tolower(my_string[i]));
      i++
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you nested your call to fgets inside a  for loop that runs 50 times.

Comment: "gets is not recommended, is fgets similar? Or is it better to use scanf?" --> use `fgets()`.

Comment: [Why `gets()` is so dangerous you should never use it!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to call `fgets()` fifty times.  It reads a line from `stdin` and writes it to `my_string`.  It seems you only want to read one line, not fifty (and keep only the last one).  The 50 is the maximum number of characters (minus one) that will be read and written to the buffer.  This limit is to prevent buffer overflow.  See [fgets()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

Try removing the `for` loop on the line before the `fgets()` call.  Also, you don't need the `my_string` in `main()`.  The corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void shift (char *my_string);//function declaration

int main()
{
  char inputstring[50];

  printf("Enter a string\n");
  shift(inputstring);
}

void shift (char *my_string) //function definition
{
  int i;
  char ch;

  if ( fgets(my_string, 50, stdin) == NULL )
    return;

  ch = my_string[0];
  for ( i=0; my_string[i]; i++ )
  {
    if(ch>='A' && ch<= 'Z') //when first char is uppercase
    {
        putchar (toupper(my_string[i]));
    }
    else if (ch>='a' && ch <= 'z')//when first char is lowercase
    {
        putchar(tolower(my_string[i]));
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Edit: Added `ch` initialization, pointed out by @thurizas.  Changed `while` loop to `for` loop.  Added check to return value of `fgets()` as suggested by @JonathanLeffler. (See his comment about the buffer size.)

Comment: I can't see where `ch` is initialized in your code (same comment about the OP code).

Comment: You should check the return status from `fgets()` before using the input string.  Also, if you type a line of 140 characters before hitting return, the first call to `fgets(my_string, 50, stdin)` will return the first 49 characters (plus a null terminator) without any newline.  The second call would return the next 49 characters without any newline.  Only the third call, which would return 42 characters plus the newline plus the null, gets a newline.

Comment: I'm a fan of [getline()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) using NULL as the first argument so it allocates the buffer for you, however much it needs to be.  But you have to `free()` it yourself when you're finished.  Dynamic memory seems beyond the level of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

- Here is another solution for your problem,

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  void convertTo (char *string);

  int main()
  {
     char inputString[50];

     printf("Enter a string\n");
     convertTo(inputString);
  }

  void convertTo (char *string)
  {
     int i;
     char ch;

     gets(string);

     ch = string[0];
     for ( i=0; string[i]; i++ )
     {
        if(ch>='A' && ch<= 'Z')
        {
           if(string[i]>='a' && string[i]<= 'z')
              string[i] = string[i] - 32;
        }
        else if (ch>='a' && ch <= 'z')
        {
           if(string[i]>='A' && string[i]<= 'Z')
              string[i] = string[i] + 32;
        }
     }
     printf("%s\n", string);
     return;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

All ASCII characters are represented by 7-bits. (thus the term 7-bit ASCII) The only bitwise difference between *lower-case* and *upper-case* is that bit-5 (the sixth bit) is set for lowercase and cleared (unset) for uppercase. This allows a simple bitwise conversion between lowercase and uppercase (either by adding/subtracting `32` or by simply flipping bit-5 directly.)

```
      +-- lowercase bit
      |
a = 01100001    A = 01000001
b = 01100010    B = 01000010
c = 01100011    C = 01000011
...
```

This allows a simple test and conversion if the first character is upper-case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXC = 50 };

char *shift (char *my_string);

int main (void)
{
    char inputstring[MAXC] = {0};;

    printf ("\n Enter a string: ");
    if (shift (inputstring))
        printf (" my_string is  : %s\n", inputstring);

    return 0;
}

char *shift (char *my_string)
{
    char *p;

    if (!(p = fgets (my_string, MAXC, stdin))) return NULL;

    if (*p == '\n') return NULL;   /* Enter only pressed  */

    if ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z')    /* test for upper case */
        for (; *p; p++)            /* convert lower/upper */
            if ('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z') *p &= ~(1 << 5);

    return my_string;
}
```

**Example Use**

```
$ ./bin/case_1st_to_upper

 Enter a string: this is my string
 my_string is  : this is my string

$ ./bin/case_1st_to_upper

 Enter a string: This is my string
 my_string is  : THIS IS MY STRING
```